# Naming a nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

I am trying to set names to a nested list. 
The example below shows the structure of the list. 
Here the content is "class" in my case there are tables.
I would like to name the first elements to varA and the second to var B. This would give something like:

```
[[varA1]]
[[varA1]][[varB1]]
```

Here is the structure of the nested list:

```
varA = paste0("varA", 1:10)
varB = paste0("varB", 1:3)

library(foreach)
tabs = foreach(j = 1:length(varA)) %do% {
  main = varA[j]
  mytabs = lapply(1:length(varB), class)
}
```

How can I set names to this list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `setNames` twice:

```
setNames(lapply(tabs, setNames, varB), varA)
#$varA1
#$varA1$varB1
#[1] "integer"
#
#$varA1$varB2
#[1] "integer"
# ...
```